# Laravel - How to dynamically load content in same view after submit in drop down list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

After selecting an option from drop down list, I am submitting it to a controller function which is returning required data in a different view. I want it to load the view in the same page (possibly inside a div) as the drop down list where I am submitting it. (I am new to Laravel and PHP)

The following is my clinic.blade.php file which lists clinics in drop down.

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'clinicIndex', 'method' => 
       'POST'])!!}

    <label> Select Clinics </label>
    <select name = "clinic">
        @foreach($clinics as $clinic)
            <option value="{{$clinic->clinicID}}"> {{$clinic->clinicName}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

        {{Form::submit('DisplayDoctors', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline- 
     primary'])}}
   {{Form::close()}}
```

The Submit is accessing my controller method via clinicIndex Route defined as below in web.php

```
   Route::post('/clinicTest', 'ClinicController@clinicIndex')- 
   >name('clinicIndex');
```

This is the function in controller

```
public function clinicIndex(Request $request)
    {
        $selectedClinic = $request->clinic;

        $clinicInfo = Clinic::where('id', '=', $selectedClinic)->get();

        $dbArray = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("SELECT * FROM bp_admin.tdbsrv WHERE iClinicId = $selectedClinic");

        $dbInfo = $dbArray[0];

        $remoteConnection = DatabaseConnection::setConnection($dbInfo);

        $doctors = $remoteConnection->select("SELECT tUsers.sSalutation, tLocationPhysician.iPhysicianId, tUsers.sFirstName,
                    tUsers.sLastName,tUsers.iPhysNum,tUsers.sDateHired,
                tPhysician.bLocum,tPhysician.bResident,
                tPhysician.dStartDay,tPhysician.dEndDay
                from tUsers
                inner join tLocationPhysician
                inner join tPhysician
                where
                tLocationPhysician.iLocationId = $selectedClinic
                and tPhysician.iId = tLocationPhysician.iPhysicianId
                and tPhysician.iPhysNum = tUsers.iPhysNum
                and tUsers.bArchived =0
                and tLocationPhysician.bArchived =0
                and tPhysician.bArchived =0
                order by tUsers.sFirstName asc");

        return view('pages.show')->with('doctors', $doctors);
    }
```

You can see that it is returning the table in a different view (opens a new page). Instead I want it to load the table in same view after submitting my selection from drop down.

I tried doing this in my clinic.blade.php

```
<div class="container" id="dispDoctors"> </div>
```

And added an ajax script in the same view

```
<script>
function loadDocContent(){
    $('#dispDoctors').load('/loadDocs');
}
</script>
```

For testing dynamic load, I defined the function for "/loadDocs" same as my controller function clinicIndex() in web.php. I am stuck how to proceed from here. As I am not sure how to pass my drop down selection to the jquery function.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out that it can be done using ajax. I am returning the view as a html and loading it in my original view.

This is my blade file

```
@extends('layouts.apptest')


@section('content')

@include('inc.messages')

<br>


<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        {{Form::open(array('url'=>'', 'files'=>true))}}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Select clinics</label>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" name="clinic" id="clinic">
                    @foreach($clinics as $clinic)
                        <option value="{{$clinic->clinicID}}"> {{$clinic->clinicName}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

        {{Form::close()}}
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container" id="dispDoctors">

</div>

@endsection

@section('script')

<script>

    $('#clinic').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);

        var clinic_sel = e.target.value;

        //ajax

        $.get('/ajax-clinic?clinic_sel=' +clinic_sel, function(data){
            //success data
            $('#dispDoctors').html(data.html);
        });
    });

</script>

@endsection
```

and this is the route I am setting up in web.php

```
Route::get('/ajax-clinic', function(){

    $clinic_sel = Input::get('clinic_sel');

    $clinicInfo = Clinic::where('id', '=', $clinic_sel)->get();

        $dbArray = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("SELECT * FROM bp_admin.tdbsrv WHERE iClinicId = $clinic_sel");

        $dbInfo = $dbArray[0];

        $remoteConnection = DatabaseConnection::setConnection($dbInfo);

        $doctors = $remoteConnection->select("SELECT tUsers.sSalutation, tLocationPhysician.iPhysicianId, tUsers.sFirstName,
                    tUsers.sLastName,tUsers.iPhysNum,tUsers.sDateHired,
                tPhysician.bLocum,tPhysician.bResident,
                tPhysician.dStartDay,tPhysician.dEndDay
                from tUsers
                inner join tLocationPhysician
                inner join tPhysician
                where
                tLocationPhysician.iLocationId = $clinic_sel
                and tPhysician.iId = tLocationPhysician.iPhysicianId
                and tPhysician.iPhysNum = tUsers.iPhysNum
                and tUsers.bArchived =0
                and tLocationPhysician.bArchived =0
                and tPhysician.bArchived =0
                order by tUsers.sFirstName asc");




        $returnView = view('pages.test')->with('doctors', $doctors)->render();

        return response()->json(array('success' =>true, 'html' =>$returnView));


});
```

You can see in my blade file that I am loading the html returned by the ajax call.

Thanks to other answers as well!

Answer (score 0):

Use axios call to submit form and receive response from controller.
Example code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57523553/5728565

Comment: Given that OP already has jQuery installed, they'd be better off using `$.ajax` instead of installing a second package to do the same exact thing.

Comment: Ajax is fine too. But i like axios name. AXIOS

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax or Pjax to load the dynamically content in the web page,
When using Ajax or Pjax you must return response in json format from controller. [follow this link](https://hdtuto.com/article/jquery-ajax-post-request-example-in-laravel-57)

Comment: It's common, but not *required* to return JSON. You could return HTML from a Blade template and insert that in place of the element, for example.